# Howto catch exceptions thrown by built-in transform in Apache Beam (in this case JSON Parsing)

Tags: json, apache-beam

My pipeline is as follows (where StringToKVTransForm, kafkaoutput, kafkainput are transforms I created or configured elsewhere; the focus is on ParseJsons here as it is a built-in transform

```
try {
    PCollection<MyClass> myObjects = p
        .apply(kafkaInput.withoutMetadata())
        .apply(Values.create())
        .apply(ParseJsons.of(MyClass.class)).setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(MyClass.class))
        .apply(AsJsons.of(MyClass.class))
        .apply(new StringToKvTransform())
        .apply(kafkaOutput);
    } catch (Throwable e){
        log.info("Unexpected error", e);
    }
    log.info("pipeline initialized");
    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
```

The problem here is that for various reasons the data I'm getting may not always be the correct json format; unfortunately, this causes the entire pipeline to crash with the exception

> org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse a path.to.MyClass from JSON value: {
>       "***myIncorrectJsonString***"
>   }

In this case I would like my pipeline to keep on going and ignore the incorrect input event, however, I don't see how...

The reason is that this is a built-in transform (ParseJsons), and it seems to throw the error to a place over which I don't have control and which causes the entire program to crash.

[All](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/handling-invalid-inputs-in-dataflow) [the](https://medium.com/@vallerylancey/error-handling-elements-in-apache-beam-pipelines-fffdea91af2a) tutorials I've seen recommend to catch the error in the transform, which is obviously not an option here.

My goto solution would be to extend ParseJsons class and catch the error, but it has a private constructor and therefore cannot be extended.

Any ideas, or do I have to write my own ParseJsons transform class?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think their is any clean way to do it.
However, If you plan to write your own transform then it will be great if you can enhance `ParseJsons` to add an optional output stream of invalid json. It might be useful in general.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so as well. If you turn this into an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think their is any clean way to do it. However, If you plan to write your own transform then it will be great if you can enhance ParseJsons to add an optional output stream of invalid json. It might be useful in general.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add for reference to what Ankur said before that some work has already been done in [BEAM-5638](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5638) to add exception handling but it is not yet fully done/merged for JSON transforms.

EDIT: [Exceptions handling for Json transforms](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8100) was recently [merged](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/9499) and it will be available soon in Beam 2.17 release.